# Questioning the accuracy of Math.sqrt on method

Tags: java

I created a method to run through an array add the numbers together in the array and then find the square root of the total. But when i checked the square root of the total on a calculator I got an entirely different answer and I was concerned.

The answer I got on the calculator was 3.16227766017.
When I ran the code the answer I got was 2.4850206733870595

I am a beginner to coding but I wanted to make sure I did not make an error somewhere in my code. Code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   double array1[] = {1,2,3,4};
   double total = 0;

   for(double x : array1){
       total += x;
       total = Math.sqrt(total);
   }

   System.out.println(total);

}
```

run:

```
2.4850206733870595
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: The answers below are, of course, correct. As a more general lesson -- we're often tempted to suspect language-level bugs when we can't figure out what we're doing wrong. This temptation is nearly always misguided, however.

Answer (score 3):

You want to compute the square root *after* the `for` loop finishes:

```
for (double x : array1) {
    total += x;
}
total = Math.sqrt(total);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Manouti. Fixed problem :-)

Comment: +1, though it would be better not to reuse the `total` variable at all. Changing the meaning of a variable (first it means the running total, then it means the square-root of the final total) is always a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

your error is that *you are changing total and setting it equal to the square root every time inside the for loop*

```
   for(double x : array1){
       total += x;
       total = Math.sqrt(total);
   }
```

*which is obviously wrong*. just do it *once* when the loop is done:

```
class root {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

   double array1[] = {1,2,3,4};
   double total = 0;

   for(double x : array1){
       total += x;

   }
   total = Math.sqrt(total);
   System.out.println(total);
} }
```

and you will get the *correct result when you print*

```
3.1622776601683795
```

Comment: Thank you adrCoder for your help.  Fixed.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept my answer by clicking the tick box on the left of my answer, below the arrow